# Getting req.body and req.file as empty when uploading file with axios

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, nuxt.js, multer

Here is the frontend:

```
let file = this.$refs.file.files[0] //"this" refers to vue
  let data = new FormData();
  data.append("image", file, file.fileName);
  data.append("content", this.content);
  data.append("title", this.title);
  data.append("action_type", "add_article");

  axios
    .post("http://localhost:3000/api", data, {
      headers: {
        // "accept": "application/json",
        // "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
        // "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
        // "auth": util.getCheckedToken(),
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      alert("success!", response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      alert("fail!", error);
    });
```

Some part of backend:

```
app.use(multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => { cb(null, '../static/images'); },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => { cb(null, my_random.fileName(file.originalname)); }
  }),
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => { cb(null, "image/png image/jpg image/jpeg".split(' ').includes(file.mimetype)); }
}).single('image'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

See tags for the tools I am using. I get no error message and req.file and req.body are empty. What can be the reason of the problem?

Comment: did you try your api with postman?

Comment: @ali-hosseini no. I don't know how to try my api with postman. I don't even understand what it means.

Comment: i want to make shore that your API is working fine without your `nuxt` app so for that purpose there is a soft wares like `postman` and `insomnia` that help you do that. you can get postman from `https://www.postman.com/` and insomnia from `https://insomnia.rest/` and then install which one you like (these two are doing almost same thing and installing one of them is Enough) then in the app you enter your URL and call it with‍ `post‍‍‍‍` method (there is a lots of video of these tools in YouTube). then test your API and see if it works or not

Comment: @ali-hosseini api works with standard (text-only) forms.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem trying to send a text/csv file, fixed by parsing the content type before the route. 
Like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: multipart/form-data}));
```

Before

```
app.use(multer({}))
```

> bodyParser.raw([options]) returns middleware that parses all bodies as a Buffer and only looks at requests where the Content-Type header matches the type option

Comment: This answer would be better if you included an explanation of why this is the answer.